# Converting odd format to [datetime] in powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, datetime

I'm writing something to get the installation date for a certain program, but I can't seem to convert the number that is returned into a weird date format (yyyyMMdd). I've tried casting it to `[datetime]`, but that returns the error below.

This may be an easy fix, but it's something I haven't run across yet. Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

```
$test = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'exampleProgram'} | select installdate
```

```
[datetime]$test.installdate
Cannot convert value "20160628" to type "System.DateTime". Error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:1 char:1
+ [datetime]$test.installdate
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocationWithFormatProvider`
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your date "20160628"
Try:

```
[datetime]::ParseExact($Date,"yyyyMMdd",$null)
```

and you get:

```
Tuesday, June 28, 2016 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: You barely beat me to it! But out of curiosity, why pass $null instead of defining a CultureInfo?

Comment: $null means current culture (from the doc: "If provider is null, the CultureInfo object that corresponds to the current culture is used."

Comment: Looking at MSDN further, it appears None is the default, behind the scenes it sets it to Invariant as well.

Comment: indeed, I guess it's a faster way than entering `[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture` :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to parse the date to a variable using invariant cultureInfo and a custom format:

```
$DateTimeVariable = [DateTime]::ParseExact("20160628", "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

or

```
$DateTimeVariable = [DateTime]::ParseExact($test.installdate, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
```